# Invalid option for TestType configured, should be a valid TestType. Integration with AWS DeviceFarm and AWS Code pipeline

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-device-farm

I currently have created my s3 bucket which has a zip folder uploaded with the iOS ipa file and my appium test files. This zip folder is called Tests.zip. In my second stage of code pipeline, I have tried to select APPIUM_RUBY or Appium Ruby. And Tests.zip under the Test Field. It keeps on throwing "Invalid option for TestType configured" error. And it doesn't tell me what exactly is improperly configured. Does anyone have any clues about what this error could be?

Comment: I'm having same problem.. did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=932346#932346

The only TestType supported with a Code Pipeline integration are:

- CALABASH
- INSTRUMENTATION
- UIAUTOMATION
- UIAUTOMATOR
- XCTEST
- XCTEST_UI